# AngularJS posted bytestream ends up being larger when PHP receives

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I am having a problem with a POSTed binary stream "growing" in transit/upon reception between an AngularJS app and a PHP backend.

The POST is pretty common to what I've done elsewhere...however, this mixes text and binary data... I'm not sure if this is sufficient...

```
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'putInitialPicture.php',
        data : {
            "xuserid" : $scope.user.id,
            "xauthtoken" : $scope.user.authtoken,
            "data" : picdata
        }
    };
    console.log("posting....");
    $http(req)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("returned from post");
            console.log(data);
            $scope.sync($scope.user.id);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error result");
            console.log(data);
    });
```

In the PHP code on the receiving function, I do the normal

```
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $_POST = json_decode($postdata, true);
```

to obtain the posted data

Later in the script, after validations are performed, and the destination filename is determined the data is written out with a simple

```
 file_put_contents("$basename/$fname",$_POST['data']);
```

This is where things get... interesting.

The written file (an image file - a JPG) is not the same as I read on the Angular side.  The file (as reported by Angular code that reads the data) is 5727 bytes.

The size on disk, after the data is POSTed, decoded, and written to disk by PHP, is 9992 bytes.

Somewhere between the server, the client and the server, it has not quite doubled.  I can discount the initial GET operation, as the content being retrieved is being reported as the correct size.

It would seem that somewhere in the POST there's something happening to the binary stream to make it able to be sent that is more than a simple JSON decode is able to handle.... but I cant figure out what.

Is there a Header I need to set on the POST to have the webserver decode the data properly?  or is there an additional decoding of the $_POST['data'] object needed prior to use?

I'm not sure what to try next here.. the questions/answers I google are all simple text... not a combination text/binary post.

**EDIT - Solution - sort of**

Sending the binary data is just a bad idea.  Instead I opted for reuse of an Upload service I already had working.  This required creation of a File object (more generically a blob) that I could toss the bytes downloaded from the remote server into, resulting in:

```
    $scope.CreateBlob = function(Data, contentType) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        var sliceSize = 1024;
        var byteCharacters = Data;
        var bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
        var slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
        var byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

        for (var sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
            var begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
            var end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

            var bytes = new Array(end - begin);
            for (var offset = begin, i = 0 ; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
                bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
            }
            byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
        }
        return new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });             
    }
```

and replacing the $http.post(...) with

```
    var blob = $scope.CreateBlob(  picdata  ,"image/jpg");
    $scope.files = [];
    $scope.files.push(blob);
```

Already having a $watch set on $scope.files the upload "just happens".

The weird thing now though... the $http.get(...) returns a picdata string that is shorter than the server says it is.  According to the headers, the length the image should be 5886 bytes...

**Accept-Ranges:bytes

Cache-Control:max-age=84600, public, no-transform

Content-Length:5886

Content-Type:image/jpeg

Date:Sun, 27 Sep 2015 04:06:10 GMT

ETag:"c01bf-16fe-520b2957e00e9"

Expires:Mon, 28 Sep 2015 03:36:10 GMT

Last-Modified:Sun, 27 Sep 2015 03:57:47 GMT

Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)**

However, when I log the **picdata.length** I'm getting **5727 bytes**

Different problem.. different day..

Comment: never sent image as json....should consider sending formData object. Angular has no image api...how is image being read?

Comment: @charlietfl .. Image is being read with a simple `$http.get($url)` with the above snippet as the `.success` clause.... the byte string that comes back matches the size on disk of the original file.

Are you suggesting avoiding the $http.post in this instance, and rolling my own?

Perhaps pre-encoding to a base64 chunk data set like form data could be done, then decoding on the server?

Comment: I would have thought a simple url(en/de)code would have worked... but the resulting file is too large (it grew from 5727 bytes to 9992 bytes .... I just dont understand that.)

Should I not be able to post as a string using `encodeURIComponent(string)` in the JS side and then `$decoded=urldecode($_POST['data']);` in the PHP ??

I thought the whole idea behind URL encoding was that it encoded the nasties that would cause problems in transit... it shouldn't be adding unknowns...